# Multiple ng-switch-when directives in a single HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Below is a simplified version of what I want to do.

```
    <div ng-switch on='stepNumber' >
       <div ng-switch-when="1" ng-switch-when="2" ng-switch-when="3" >One, Two, Three</div>
       <div ng-switch-when="4" >Four</div>
       <div ng-switch-when="5" ng-switch-when="10">Five, Ten</div>
    </div>
```

The complex version doesn't seem to work, and the code would be confusing for people to review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write separate element with `ng-switch-when` for each condition:

<kbd>[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/QYi31T?p=preview)</kbd>

```
Step Number: <input type="text" ng-model="stepNumber">

<div ng-switch on="stepNumber">
  <div ng-switch-when="1">One, Two, Three</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="2">One, Two, Three</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="3">One, Two, Three</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="4">Four</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="5">Five, Ten</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="10">Five, Ten</div>
</div>
```

<sub>Note: This requires AngularJS v1.1.3+</sub>

OR, if you're on AngularJS v.1.1.5+ than `ngIf` might be cleaner solution:

<kbd>[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/sfFH0H?p=preview)</kbd>

Step Number:

```html
Step Number: <input type="text" ng-model="stepNumber">

<div ng-if="stepNumberWithin(['1', '2', '3'], stepNumber)">One, Two, Three</div>
<div ng-if="stepNumberWithin(['4'], stepNumber)">Four</div>
<div ng-if="stepNumberWithin(['5', '10'], stepNumber)">Five, Ten</div>
```

```js
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.stepNumberWithin = function(arr, number){
    console.log(arr, number);
    return arr.indexOf(number) !== -1;
  }

});
```